# Is two-dimensional array access/modification time-constant?

Tags: c++, arrays, time

Is accessing or modifying an element in a 2D array in C++ time-constant?

For example:

```
/* C++ */
int nRow, nColumn;
int **data;
...
void set (int x, int y, int n) {
    data[x][y] = n;
}
int get (int x, int y) {
    return data[x][y];
}
```

Is this time-dependent on `nRow` and/or `nColumn`?

Comment: It's O(1) from the language's point of view. Cache effects may apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends.

The operation is not.  `data[x][y]` turns into `*(data * max_y + y)`.

It can make a difference though if it causes a cache miss or something like that.  If `data` is big enough it can nullify the prefetcher and cache sharing.  Both are things that can affect speed greatly depending on the context.

Comment: `data + (x * max_y + y) * sizeof(int)` is much closer to what it actually is. As far as 'time complexity' is concerned, that line is O(1) i.e. constant, but the point about the cache miss is great - it helps show just how detached time complexity is from reality.